# iOS - navigate From AppDelegate to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate

I try to navigate to certain ViewController after I get remote Notification 
It crashes after this code any help please
My storyboard like this 
SWRevealViewController -> NavViewController -> UIViewController 
I want to reach this UIViewController

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
// my ViewController I want navigate to UITableViewController call home_tableview

    Home_tableView *home =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home_view"];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:home animated:NO];

}
```

The Error I get

```
2015-01-20 13:04:14.379 SchoolLink[1304:416727] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:(0x25bd749f 0x3338dc8b 0x25af30b3 0x2909d06b 0x11d48f 0x29099d0f 0x29099a7d 0x2909f953 0x2910643d 0x111dbd 0x2930286b 0x292fa54d 0x2c3680d1 0x25b9dd7d 0x25b9d041 0x25b9bb7b 0x25ae93c1 0x25ae91d3 0x2cee70a9 0x290f8fa1 0x12b7ad 0x3390daaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: maybe your storyobard name is: MainStoryboard  and not only Main

Comment: Aparently *home is null. Did you check that? Double check its identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: My storyboard called main only , and my storyboard identifier called home_view I am sure about this

Comment: What is your callstack when the error is thrown? (For formatting purposes please edit your question and add the callstack. Don't post it as comment.

Comment: Or `home` is nil or inside your `Home_tableView` you are inserting something nil into an array. Try to put a breakpoint inside the `init` or `viewDidLoad` of your `Home_tableView` and check if it is happening.

Comment: this method in appDelegate , after i get notification

Comment: Thank you I get error here [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have an `UINavigationController` in your storyboard which embeds your view controllers.

If that's the case, your code should work without any issues.

I've tested it in a new project with two view controllers and one navigation controller as the initial view and everything is fine.

If you're certain that you have all the storyboard identifiers right, and that your `initial View` in `Interface Builder` is an `UINavigationController` that embeds all of your `ViewControllers`, then you have some issues elsewhere, not in the code you've pasted in.

Since your error is related to `insertObjectAtIndex:` I believe there's some data you instantiate your UITableViewController with in the normal workflow of the app (when segueing to it) and when you try to present the UITableView controller in a clean state from a notification, that data is missing, hence the crash.

Check where you try to add an object to an array at a given index.

The problem is either in the class that receives the notification (I guess it's your `AppDelegate` class), either in the `UITableViewController` class, somewhere in the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Home_tableView *home =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home_view"];
[self.window setRootViewController:home]
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: You might want to edit your answer, once @mina wants to push the `home` viewcontroller into the main navigation controller. Not to set `home` as the root viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
Home_tableView*svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home_view"]; 
// Configure the new view controller here.   
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```